# How to correct float value range?

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, sed

I'm tryring to migrate data from Sybase to SQL Server but found some incorrect records.

My record is `2.466987812E-304,2.75859452825E-323,2.4669878237E-314`. In this first value is correct because range for float is between 2.2250738585072014e-308 and 1.797693134862315708e+308. But 2'nd and 3'rd value is incorrect.

How to correct these values using sed? I want to replace value which having exponent greater than 308 has to replace by 2.2250738585072014e-308.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS=ORS=FS=","}{split($0,a,"-");if(a[2]>308) $0="2.2250738585072014e-308"}1' inputfile
```

Explanation: This will divide all the text into smaller chunks separated by RS (,). and then use awk's split function to further split the fields into parts separated by (-). If the value of second part a[2] is more than 308, do some action. "1" means print the line.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Pravin you can use `awk '...............'| 
sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /'` if you want to remove last comma.